# Закрыть flash уведомление при нажатии кнопки

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Мои уведомления выводятся так:

```
<% flash.each do |name, message| %>
  <div class="alert">
    <button class="close">&times;</button>
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Как я могу закрыть окно уведомлений при нажатии кнопки из этого блока?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% flash.each do |name, message| %>
  <div class="alert">
    <button class="close" onclick="var elem = document.querySelector('#alert');elem.style.display = 'none';">&times;</button>
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```